# What do I need to register a user or define a group?

Tags: ejabberd

As I just discovered eJabberd, when setting the authentication to internal.
Where would the logic of authentication be? or it will just match username with password in the mnesia DB?

Also, when registering a user, for example: using elixir, register a user would be as:

```
:ejabberd_auth.try_register("test", "localhost", "passw0rd")
```

Where would the new user be stored?

And, if authentication is external, what should I return as a response if successful or failure authentication?

Can start & use the eJabberd server without writing any server side code? if for example, all users are stored in an external db?

Comment: Hi @simo. I  am tryiing to teach myself how to write an Ejabberd chat app in Erlang. I am really stuck and I've been at it for days (actually about three weeks now). Resources are really limited, and the little documentation I come accross either skips some really seemingly minor detail that really gets one stuck trying to figure out how **`B`** was resolved in an **`A -> B -> C`** algorithm where **`B`** was only mentioned, or just pulled from thin air.

Comment: I have a question [HERE *(I am unable to use `ejabberd_auth` in my **helloworld** project)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220369/i-am-unable-to-use-ejabberd-auth-in-my-helloworld-project). I put a bounty on it, and was wondering if you could help in any way, if you managed to get a little pro/ ninja in Ejabberd and Erlang. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you. Hope to here from you.